# Trouble padding a Perl string array without increasing array length

Tags: perl

I have an integer value `my $reading = 1200;`.

I have an array `my @DigitField = "000000000";`

I want to replace the right-hand 4 elements of the array with `$reading`'s value, and I want to do this programmatically using Perl's length function as shown below.

I've tried.

```
my @DigitField = "000000000";
my $reading = 1200;
splice @DigitField, length(@DigitField) + 1, length $reading, $reading;
print @DigitField;
```

but I'm getting

`0000000001200`

and I want the string to remain nine characters wide.

What are some other ways to replace part of a Perl string array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are possibly confused - the `@` sigil indicates `@DigitField` is an array variable. A string is not an array.

I think you want to [format](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) the number:

```
my $reading = 1200;
my $digitfield = sprintf('%09d', $reading);
print $digitfield, "\n";
```

I added a `\n` to the end of the print, this adds a [newline](http://enwp.org/Newline). Depending on the context of your program, you may or may not want this in the final.

Comment: Yes, I did confuse it. Thanks.